# Заголовки строк и столбцов таблицы можно считать собственно-назывными предложениями?

Tags: синтаксис

Заголовки строк и столбцов таблицы можно считать собственно-назывными предложениями? Или же это более сложный случай, чем простое наименование произведения или вывеска, поскольку значение в поле таблицы синтаксически зависит от названия столбца и является по сути сказуемым (текущий рейтинг - 234). Под термин "собственно-назывные предложения" подпадают только примеры "Аптека", "Вход", "Война и мир", духи "Красная Москва" и т.п.? Как быть с заголовками строк и столбцов таблиц? Это особый случай? По факту это заголовки, но от них синтаксически зависят значения в теле таблицы? Можно ли к таблице применять обычную терминологию и искать здесь назывные предложения?    Или это особый способ представления информации?   Выскажите, пожалуйста, свое мнение.

Answer (score 1):

Таблица - высказывание, текст, состоящий из предложений, но не односоставных, а двусоставных. Собственно, по логическому содержанию таблица представляет собой одно «статистическое предложение», основными элементами которого являются подлежащие и сказуемые.

Подлежащим статистической таблицы называется объект, который характеризуется цифрами. Это может быть одна или несколько совокупностей, отдельные единицы совокупности в порядке их перечня или сгруппированные по каким-либо признакам, территориальные единицы и так далее. Обычно подлежащее таблицы дается в левой части, в наименовании строк.

Сказуемое статистической таблицы образует система показателей, которыми характеризуется объект изучения, то есть подлежащее таблицы. Сказуемое формирует верхние заголовки и составляет содержание граф с логически последовательным расположением показателей слева направо.

Примером простой перечневой таблицы является информация о наличии строительных машин в строительных управлениях региона.

**Вид машин**              **Количество машин данного вида, тыс. шт.**(информация о том, что данный вид имеется в таком-то количестве)

Экскаваторы            32,6

Скреперы               8,7

Бульдозеры             31,6

Краны передвижные      40,3

Всего                  113,2

Подлежащим таблицы является вид машин, сказуемым - количество разных их видов.

https://studopedia.ru/11_39833_nazvanie-tablitsi-obshchiy-zagolovok.html